# Characteristics of relations. Are these relations correct?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The question asks: Let $A= \{1,2,3\}$. List the ordered pairs and draw the digraph of a relation on $A$ with the given properties. I just want to check if my ordered pairs are correct or not so I have no doubts.

1. reflexive, not symmetric, and not transitive.

$$\{(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(1,3),(2,3)\}$$

2. not reflexive, symmetric, and not transitive.

$$\{(1,1),(2,2),(3,1),(1,3)\}$$

3. reflexive, symmetric, and not transitive.

$$\{(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(1,2),(2,1)\}$$

Comment: *a* relation with the properties.  Not all?  All yours are good (and there are others, of course).  Um... what's the difference between 2 and 3?  But yes, your relations are all correct.

Comment: Great, thanks, I made a mistake only meant to add 3 questions. Accidentally repeated 2.

Comment: Why exactly aren't the 1st and 3rd transitive? They might not be, but I don't see any ordered pairs that are "missing" so as to violate transitivity.

Comment: oops, @pjs36 is right.  All of these are transitive.  Replace (2,3) with (32) and 1) is good (As 1 R 3 and 3 R 2 but 1 not R 2). Add  (3,2) and (2,3) to the 2nd and you have 1 R 3 and 3 R 2 but 1 not R 2. ditto the last.

Answer (score 1):

All of your answers are correct besides the very first one. Looking at the first one, I cannot spot any instance where the ordered pairs are $not$ transitive. Hence it must be transitive. Other than that, the rest are fine.

EDIT: The last answer is also transitive as the comment below pointed out. Thank you for spotting the error.

Comment: As the Comments on the Question pointed out, the third relation is also *transitive*, but described by the OP as not transitive.